# Error handling in OpenMP

Tags: c, error-handling, openmp

I use OpenMP to parallelize `execute` function calls as follow:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(MAX_NUM_THREADS)
{
    int i = omp_get_thread_num();
    statusT[i] = prepareT();

    #pragma omp barrier
    #pragma omp single
    {
        status = init();
    } // implicit barrier

    statusT[i] = execute1T();
    statusT[i] = execute2T();
}
```

I would like to find the cleanest solution allowing to handle possible errors coming from the different function calls and captured in the `status` variables.

---

I thought about 2 solutions but I find none of them pretty/convenient to use.

1. We could put the remaining code inside an `if` clause ; but depending on the amount of `execute` function the nested `if`s can become difficult to read.
2. We could use a `goto` after each check that is failing to jump directly at the end of the parallelization. But I've always been told to avoid `goto`s.

**My questions:**

- Would you recommend one solution more than the other and why?
- Does anyone think of a better alternative ?

Comment: `goto` is perfectly reasonable for error handling in C programs. It is the preferred mechanism in the Linux kernel, and is vastly superior to nested `if`s.

Comment: I actually like nested `if`s, as they make clear the scope of the section that depends on each condition.  But even then, `goto` is often invaluable for error recovery.  Do not be afraid of using `goto` where it clarifies your code.  With that said, C *often* has better alternatives.

Comment: How about break, and continue statements?

Comment: @k_kaz what do you mean? How would you use `break` and `continue` statements in my example?

Comment: @John (both): thanks for your feedback! @JohnBollinger: what do you mean by « `goto` is often invaluable for error recovery »? Thanks

Comment: @Jav, I just mean that error-recovery strategies different from "abort on any error" often involve control flows that are represented much more simply and clearly with the help of `goto`s than without, even when using a nested-`if` style general approach.